# How query errors affect Postgresql DB performance

Tags: postgresql, error-log, postgresql-12

I have an application stored measurements data in PostgreSQL-12. 
Couple of processes write data by queries like:

```
INSERT INTO "<measurement>" (<columns>) VALUES (<values>);
```

But for some reason the `"<measurement>"` table was not created, and I got errors like:

```
ERROR:  relation "<measurement>" does not exist at character 13
```

The question is: Does massive errors count affect the DB performance?

Comment: Why would it - it's just a one-off error? Run a (longish) query a couple of times, get a timing, then run your query where a table doesn't exist and then rerun your longish query a couple of times and compare the timings - I seriously doubt if there'll be a significant difference between the before and the after!

Comment: Thank you @Vérace. Will try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does massive errors count affect the DB performance?

Not really.

It will make the error log [a bit] larger, because each error gets written there, but that should be trivial in size compared to the database itself.  Each of those writes to the log will take [some] time, but not a great deal.

What *will* get noticed is that the Application trying to *execute* these statements is failing to do so.
Each of those failures is *losing* company Data.
That matters.

At some point, the Development team for the Application will get involved and they may well start throwing rocks in *your* direction because there's a table missing from the database.  Be *prepared* for the question: "Whose responsibility *was* it to create that table in the first place?"